# php base64 encode imagecreatetruecolor

Tags: php, base64, encode

I have a php script that generates an image then outputs the image as a png.

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($graphWidth,$graphHeight);
...
*drawing routines*
...
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
```

What I now need is to get the php script to base64 encode the image data and output that string (so I can eventually pass that encoded data to a java script which decodes and adds this image to a generated pdf).

I have tried many times to get it working myself using other stackoverflow posts/answers etc. but I don't understand enough about this technology to have gotten it to work.

Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: How did you try to encode it as base64? Or you have a problem decoding it in Javascript?

Comment: I'm using an AJAX call to set the src of an html image tag with ... document.getElementById("theGraphImg").src = "graphIt.php";

When I try to encode $img like so: echo base64_encode($img);

... and I alert(xmlhttp.responseText) ... I get funky characters that I've been told are not what I need.

Comment: You mean really funky characters like those symbols and signs? After base64_encode there should be only alphanumeric characters

Comment: yes, I get non alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Hm, I think you should show us more codes, say, php, javascript and html. Just the necessary parts are okay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because the image in `$img` is a resource, not an actual PNG image.  When you call `imagepng()`, it outputs the image.

What I would do is create an output buffer, and base-64 encode it.

```
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$buffer = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();
echo base64_encode($buffer);
```

Don't forget to change your `Content-Type` header, as this is no longer `image/png`.