# Get base64 string from imagecreatetruecolor()?

Tags: php, image, base64

Is there a way to create a base64 string directly with the result from `imagecreatetruecolor()`?

Example:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $red);
$base64 = base64_encode($img);
```

The way over `imagepng()` i know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php base64 encode imagecreatetruecolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587754/php-base64-encode-imagecreatetruecolor)

Comment: @ajt, thats the way over imagepng() i know.